# Ways to detect negation in Natural Language Processing?

Tags: nlp

I am studying Natural Language Processing. What could be the ways to detect negation? There are at least two forms of negation that I can think of.

1. I do **not** like orange juice.
2. I **deny** that I like orange juice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can image a task like [NER](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-meeting-industrys-requirement-by-applying-state-of-the-art-deep-698d2b3b4ede). Your dataset will be a set of sentences with the "negation" word annotated and that's it.

*E.g.*

```py
x = "I do not like orange juice"
y = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

The model then is a classification one, and it depends on several factors which one would be the more appropriate.